# Sybase: enabling LIMIT

Tags: limit, sybase, sqlanywhere, reserved-words

Which one of these three statements is the best one to enable the keyword `LIMIT`?

```
SET OPTION RESERVED_KEYWORDS = 'LIMIT';
SET OPTION PUBLIC reserved_keywords = 'LIMIT';
SET OPTION PUBLIC.reserved_keywords = 'LIMIT';
```

Comment: Removed ase-tag to make the question more answerable.

Answer (score 0):

`SET OPTION RESERVED_KEYWORDS = 'LIMIT';` is in the [IQ SQL documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_IQ/a898e08b84f21015969fa437e89860c8/a248737984f21015a82f960e9878cbd1.html?locale=en-US&q=RESERVED_KEYWORDS).

`SET OPTION PUBLIC.reserved_keywords = 'LIMIT';` is in the [SQL Anywhere documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/61ecb3d4d8be4baaa07cc4db0ddb5d0a/814af1bc6ce210149a91b608c6f8babb.html?locale=en-US)

Adaptive Server Enterprise: [Limit/Offset](https://answers.sap.com/questions/624790/rows-limit-returns-wrong-result-when-operation-is-.html) since version [ASE 16 SP02 PL05](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/e0d4539d39c34f52ae9ef822c2060077/26d84b4ddae94fed89d4e7c88bc8d1e6.html?version=16.0.2.5&locale=en-US).